# How to get original page url/uri after request dispatcher forward

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have a Error404Servlet which is configured as error-page for 404 in web.xml:

```
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Error404</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.foo.bar.Error404Servlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <error-page>
      <error-code>404</error-code>
      <location>/error404</location>
   </error-page>
```

In this servlet i have to log the original url that caused 404, but request.getRequestURI()  always returns "/error404"

How can i get the original url? The unly ugly method i know is to create filter that puts the original url to request attribute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the request you can retrieve attributes set by the container in the event of an error:

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
```

other attributes that can provide usefull information;

```
javax.servlet.error.status_code
javax.servlet.error.exception_type
javax.servlet.error.message
javax.servlet.error.exception
```

See also this [servlet 2.3 features article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Servlets/servletapi2.3/).

Comment: hi where can i find the query params, which HTTP_Method was used and httpheaders?